# 32GB SD card shows up as two volumes. One with 256MB of space. How can I utilize the full capacity of the 32GB SD card?

Tags: partitioning, format

When I enter my 32GB SD Card to my Windows 7 PC it shows 256MB.  Running disk management shows the following (disk `H:`). How do I make one volume of 32GB?

[image]

Comment: formatting offers me only 256mb capacity

Comment: And, exactly what make and model is the SD card?

Answer (score 6):

From the [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/170794/ask-htg-how-can-i-reclaim-the-full-capacity-of-an-sd-card/)

Run DiskPart from cmd.

1. List Disk
2. choose disk X and run select disk X
3. clean
4. create partition primary.

Answer (score 2):

First, I am assuming you don't have any data on the card you wish to save.  If you do, back this data up somewhere else first.

Delete the H: partition so that the entire disk shows as Unallocated.  Then create a new partition to use all of the space.  A new NTFS partition with default settings should be good.

If you are unable to do this in Windows, there is a tool specifically used for formatting SD cards called SD Card Formatter.

SD Card Formatter:
https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/index.html

User Guide: https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/SDFormatter_4e.pdf

Comment: right clicking on the drive/partition or volume - I dont have a delete partition option

Comment: BTW: sdcard formatter shows only 256 mb. http://i.imgur.com/voHg1BE.png